# Objective C - Menubar icon click event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i have an Application with just the menubar icon.[image: Menubar icon] 
I am able to listen to menubar items: `(IBAction) preferencesMenuItemClick:(id)sender`
[image: Menubar item]

But how can i listen to the menubar icon itself? 
There is no Sent Action available for it.
[image: XCode Sent Actions]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you mean with _menu bar icon_?

Comment: If you are able to receive events for the menu bar icons, and your target menu bar icon is part of these menu bar icons, then you also receive an event for your target menu bar icon? I don't really understand, can provide a bit more information?

Comment: Hey, Nikolas, i've just updated the question. Is it more comprehensible now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get notified when user clicks on your menu bar icon (which is actually **status item**), you can use `NSMenuDelegate` `menuWillOpen:` method. This will get invoked when the status menu is about to be opened which is same as clicking on status item itself.

Note that this only works if you are using a Menu for status item. If you are using NSView or any other possible combination similar methods (loadView) has to be used.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSMenuDelegate/menuWillOpen:

Comment: Thank you so much. Life can be so easy if you know how ;)

Comment: Note that `-menuWillOpen:` will occur for things other than actual clicks of the mouse button. For example, keyboard navigation or VoiceOver.

Answer (score 1):

NSStatusItem has a `setAction:` method, which sets the selector that is sent to the receiver’s target when the receiver is clicked.

```
- (void)setAction:(SEL)action
```

However, this causes problems if the status item has a menu:

> If the receiver has a menu set, action is not sent to the target when the receiver is clicked; instead, the click causes the menu to appear.

To solve this, you can use your `action` selector to perform an action OR manually show a menu:

```
[self.statusItem setAction:@selector(menuAction:)];

...

- (void)menuAction:(id)sender {
    if ( ... ) {
        NSLog(@"Perform non-menu action!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Manually open the menu!");
        [self.statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:menu];
    }
}
```